# Setting permissions for specific programs to run as guest

Tags: permissions, node.js, npm

How do I set permissions for an HTTP server (nodejs) to run programs in `/usr/local/share/npm/` safely?

My use case is to setup my OSX box to run [cloud9](https://c9.io/) and use [titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/platform/titanium-platform/) to build iOS apps for iPhone/iPad. I got cloud9 running and am able to build an iPhone app from the browser, locally as an admin user. But while I can access the cloud9 instance from outside (via HTTP), I can not build apps as what-ever-user is when using cloud9 from afar.

It's not clear to me what user account the cloud9 instance is using because I don't know how to look that up. I'm also a little uneasy with setting executable permissions as I'm new to unix security.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of questions/answers on stackoverflow regarding nodejs and security/ports, etc.  [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164915/node-js-eacces-error-when-listening-on-most-ports?rq=1) in particular might suit you, or you may try the related questions. Note: I'm assuming OSX is similar to linux in this regard, since I'm not familiar with OSX.

Essentially, for the most part it's a matter of port forwarding; because you're not able to listen on ports below 1024 as regular user (unless you downgrade privileges), you need to forward listening from port 80 to 3000, or something like that.